# Codeigniter - storing database results in session

Tags: php, database, session, codeigniter, authentication

Hey there, i want to store some session info from a database query, upon log in,
but for some reason it isnt letting me set the session userdata!?!

Can anyone shed any light as to why?

Controller:

```
function validate_login(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', "Email address","required|valid_email");
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', "Password", "trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]");

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

  $this->login();

} else {

  $email_address = $this->input->post('email_address');
  $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
  $prev_page = $this->input->post('referrer');

  $found_user = $this->account_model->validate_user($email_address, $password); // calls to function of the same name in the model, returns array.

  if($found_user){

    $session_data = array(
      'user_id' => $found_user->user_id,
      'is_logged_in' => TRUE
    );

    // Debug code

      if($this->session->set_userdata($session_data)){
        echo "success session";
        } else {
        echo "failure session";
      }

  } else {
    //Debug code
    echo 'no user found';
  }
}
}
```

Model:

```
  function validate_user($email_address, $password){

$this->db->where('email_address', $email_address);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$query = $this->db->get('user');

if($query->num_rows() == 1){

   foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $data = $row;
      }
      return $data;

} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error? 'failure session' or 'no user found'?

Comment: you aren't every saving anything to the session...

Comment: Sorry, The error is "failure session"

Comment: @seth - $this->session->set_userdata($session_data) saves to the session, included here within an if statement for debugging, if true it would echo "success session";

Comment: whenever i print_r($session_data) i get back what i expect which is array(['user_id'] => 2, ['is_logged_in'] => 1)

Comment: what do you see when you `print_r($this->session->all_userdata())` ? Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as another answer just so I can paste this code snippet. I think everything is working as it should be. The set_userdata function returns void, so you don't need to encapsulate it in an if statement.

Instead of the following code:

```
if($this->session->set_userdata($session_data)){
    echo "success session";
    } else {
    echo "failure session";
  }
```

It should just be:

```
this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
```

You can use this function to add new data  or changing existing data in the session; it doesn't matter if there's already data in it.

**Another answer:**

Are you loading the session library? Being a commonly used library I would recommend loading it in the autoload config file, like so:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'other libraries etc');
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info Christian, i wasn't aware it returned void i figured it was true or false for some reason, hence my failure message.

Comment: I wasn't sure either, and it doesn't say anything about it in the docs, so I just dug around the session library and found out that it doesn't return anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

Well it seems to be working now, i think the problem might have been trying to set_userdata that was already set!

although i don't know why it would return FALSE if i was updating or adding to data that was there.
I made sure all session data was destroyed and cut out the conditionals and now seems to have a persistant session.